# How can I clean up this PHP code (If equals empty try next value)

Tags: php, loops

Basically I have IF loop if a result equals  empty  and try the next key (line from text file)
English not my first language so please do not flag me

key.txt contains

```
  randomkeyline
  randomkeyline
  randomkeyline
```

Now for the below code it goes 30 lines, how can i make it just try the next line try the next key (line?  instead of having 300 lines of code

```
$key = file("keys.txt");//file in to an array
+1
$mykey = $key[1];
echo $mykey;

if($q){
$xml = file_get_contents("https://www.exampleurl.com/?q&key=$key(try next line if empty)");
}

echo $xml;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the keys in an array, and loop until you get a successful reply.

```
$keys = file("key.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $xml = file_get_contents("https://exampleurl.com/?s=35&key=$key");
    if ($xml) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you would this work? like $keys = ["346523634," "3564326"]

Comment: @DOMDocumentVideoSource ... why not just try and see?

Comment: because each day i have to add several new keys  and i only want to add one line, which is one key.   as i have to do this to 40 files.

Comment: even if i could just put each key in a text file    and retrive by line number if first key fails  thank you so muich for help

Comment: It doesn't matter where the keys come from. Just put them in an array and do this.

Comment: ok i edited to try to make it come a text file (if xml= nothing try next line) could someone please assist i hope this data is useful to everyone> thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get the array from the file.

Comment: Brilliant code Barmar! I got it working . how to pay u .

Comment: this my old code having trouble converting it.  if($q){
$xml = file_get_contents("https://example.com/?&key=$key");
if ($xml == ""){$xml = file_get_contents("https://example.com/?&key=$key2");}
if ($xml == ""){$xml = file_get_contents("https://example.com/?&key=$key3");}
if ($xml == ""){$xml = file_get_contents("https://example.com/?&key=$key4");}

}  else

Comment: also the code you provided gets the last  line, not the next line. basically what im doing is have a set of google api keys, if one reaches its qouta just want to roll over to the next

Comment: It gets the first one that returns a non-empty response